Recalculate/Draw SVG paths on canvas with Skia in Delphi?
Are there built in functions in skia for a canvas or something I should use to recalculate my paths when a user resizes the form or do I need to create the functions and calculations myself?
I am new to delphi and using skia to draw images onto a canvas. When the form resizes, i want to Scale and stretch. They need to stay consistent with an svg background image as it resizes. Scale would be most important.

This helped me:
ACanvas.Save;
try
  ACanvas.Scale(2, 2);
  ACanvas.DrawPath(LPath, LPaint);
finally
  ACanvas.Restore;
end;

But ideally I'd still like to know if there aren't any other better ways.
